# Transform the points in the world to the camera coordinate frame

Tags: matlab, matrix, camera

I have X: 3 by N matrix containing the point coordinates in 3-dimensional world coordinates. 2 intrinsic parameters: cam.f, focal length(scalar) and cam.c image center (principal point, 2 by 1 vector). and 2 extrinsic parameters cam.R : camera rotation matrix (3 by 3) and cam.t camera translation matrix (3 by 1 vector).

The question I have is, how to transform the points in the world to camera coordinates in MATLAB.